# Add fade effect to jQuery image replace on hover script

Tags: javascript, jquery

There were a few topics about this already but they didn't quite help in my case. I've written a small script to change the image source of some social icons when hovered over. I'm trying to add a fadeIn and fadeOut effect so it isn't just a straight up image swap. Here is my script:

```
$(".social_icons").live('hover', function() {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == "social_icons") {
    this.src = this.src.replace("-black","-color");
  } else {
    this.src = this.src.replace("-color","-black");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

How can I add a fadeIn/fadeOut effect to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".social_icons").live('hover', function() {
    var $curr = $(this);
     if ($(this).attr("class") == "social_icons") {
        $curr.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $curr.attr('src', this.src.replace("-black","-color"));
            $curr.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    } else {
        $curr.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $curr.attr('src', this.src.replace("-color","-black"));
            $curr.fadeIn('slow');
        });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

Comment: `$(this).fadeIn('slow')` really? if you can hover over an element it's visible of course.

Comment: oops .. missed that ..@undefined .. Thanks for pointing it out.. Check the updated code

Comment: Thank you, that worked just great but it actually made me realize that I don't really want to utilize it after all. I was ideally trying to have it fade into the color version and back out again rather than the complete fade out of the first image and fade in of the second image. I'm not sure if that's possible though...